# Eclipse - unfortunately app has stopped - ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, classnotfoundexception

I am new in Android, and still learning about java, xml, ect. This is my first project, but still get error. in emulator says: "Unfortunately App has stopped".. I Need HELP.. Please...!!

Logcat's error log

```
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): Process: id.co.kendaricall, PID: 1627
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{id.co.kendaricall/id.co.kendaricall.KategoryActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "id.co.kendaricall.KategoryActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/id.co.kendaricall-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/id.co.kendaricall-2, /system/lib]]
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "id.co.kendaricall.KategoryActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/id.co.kendaricall-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/id.co.kendaricall-2, /system/lib]]
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
11-10 22:42:28.700: E/AndroidRuntime(1627):     ... 11 more
```

this is the manifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="id.co.kendaricall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/KendariCallTheme">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" 
                      android:required="false" />

    <activity android:name=".KategoryActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".KontakDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TemplateActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KontakListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PencarianActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".KontakFavoritActivity" />
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEDGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: The exception is exactly what it says.  It couldn't find the class.  Is the KategoryActivity class named correctly and in the correct package?  Does it even exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all of tour activity classes put in any other package. Go to id.co.kendaricall folder and check weather activity classes present or not. If not then find folder where all classes kept. Suppose all classes kept in package id.co.kendaricall.activity so change in manifest

```
<activity android:name="activity.KontakDetailActivity" />
<activity android:name="activity.SettingActivity" />
<activity android:name="activity.TemplateActivity" />
<activity android:name="activity.KontakListActivity" />
<activity android:name="activity.PencarianActivity" />
<activity android:name="activity.KontakFavoritActivity" />
```

Thanks.